# How to change HDFS replication factor for HIVE alone

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

Our current HDFS Cluster has replication factor 1.But to improve the performance and reliability(node failure) we want to increase Hive intermediate files (hive.exec.scratchdir) replication factor alone to 5. Is it possible to implement that ?

Regards,
Selva

Answer (score 0):

See if **`-setrep`** helps you.

**setrep**

**Usage:**

```
hadoop fs -setrep [-R] [-w] <numReplicas> <path>
```

Changes the **`replication factor`** of a file. If **path is a directory** then the command **recursively** changes the **`replication factor`** of all files under the directory tree rooted at path.

**Options:**

```
The -w flag requests that the command wait for the replication to complete. This can potentially take a very long time.

The -R flag is accepted for backwards compatibility. It has no effect.
```

**Example:**

```
hadoop fs -setrep -w 3 /user/hadoop/dir1

hadoop fs -setrep -R -w 100 /path/to/hive/warehouse
```

Reference: [-setrep](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)