# Does Hive duplicate data?

Tags: hive

I have a large log file which I loaded in to `HDFS`. `HDFS` will replicate to different nodes based on rack awareness.

Now I load the same file into a hive table. The commands are as below:

```
create table log_analysis (logtext string) STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/log/apache.log' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE log_analysis;
```

Now when I go and see the '/user/hive/warehouse/' directory there is a table file and copying it to local, it has all the log file data.

My question is: the existing file in `HDFS` is replicated. Then loading that file in hive table, stored on `HDFS` also gets replicated.

Is that not the same file stored 6 times (assuming that replication factor is 3) ? That would be such a waste of resources.

Comment: This is correct. Hence you must judiciously choose what data would you want to keep in HDFS.

Comment: If you want to selectively change the replication factor of the log files (or the Hive table) have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292277/how-to-change-hdfs-replication-factor-for-hive-alone

Answer (score 3):

Your question indicates that you have created an `INTERNAL` table using hive and you are loading data into `HIVE` table from `HDFS` location.

When you load data into an internal table using `LOAD DATA INPATAH` command, It moves data from the primary location to another location. In your case, it should be `/user/hive/warehouse/log_analysis`. So basically it provides new address and new HDFS location of the data and you won't be seeing anything in the previous location.

When you move data from one location to another location on HDFS. NameNode receives a new location of the data and it deletes all old metadata for that data. Hence there won't be any duplicate information of the data and the data and there will be only 3 replication and it will be stored only 3 times.

I hope it clear to you.

Answer (score 3):

Correct, In case you are loading the data from `HDFS` , the data moves from `HDFS` to the `/user/hive/warehouse/yourdatabasename/tablename`.